# Coalescing nulls (fill nulls with last value)

Tags: java

I'm trying to replace nulls in a Java list with last value prior to a null character.  Similar questions have been posted in SQL, but I must be overlooking any Java solution.

Imagine I have a container:

```
[1,2,3, null, null, 8, null, 9, null, null]
```

Is there a coalesce, or similar function out-of-the-box available to replace each null with the last non-null value?  EG:

```
[1,2,3,3,3,8,8,9,9,9]
```

I'd prefer not to have to write one, since I need it to work on Integers, Doubles, Strings etc...

Being new to java, is it possible to write a single implementation of this, which would work on any object type?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no built-in solution, but you could write a generic one with either `Object`s or using a `<type>` parameter. How do you propose handling the situation where `array[0] == null`?

Comment: Didn't think about it, good question.  For my case, probably have to just mask with 0

Comment: Sounds like a generic reactive setup could handle this--store the state of the last non-null and emit it on incoming null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the best solution, but it's one approach that is mostly functional. Keep in mind that since we are not `clone`ing the objects when coalescing, we will end up storing multiple references to the same object. Worth considering for non-immutable types.

Using generics:

```
class Utility<T> {
    public void coalesce(T[] a, T mask) {
        if (a[0] == null) {
            a[0] = mask;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] == null) {
                a[i] = a[i-1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And calling:

```
Utility<String> stringUtil = new Utility<>();
String[] theArray = {null, "one", "two", null, null, "four", "five", null};
stringUtil.coalesce(theArray, "N/A");
```

Without generics:

```
public void coalesce(Object[] a, Object mask) {
    if (a[0] == null) {
        a[0] = mask;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] == null) {
            a[i] = a[i-1];
        }
    }
}
```

For mutable types, the first approach could be improved by changing `T` to `T extends Cloneable` and then calling `.clone()` in each set operation. Additionally the first approach could be further improved by use of a `static` method.

Comment: Thank you.  I will have to read up on generics, as I don't fully understand them.  PS, would coalesce take an ArrayList as the first argument?  IE, does Object[] include ArrayLists ?

Comment: @AdamHughes I've added a little example of how to call the method with generics also.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve the generalisation you are looking for you may wish to consider an `Iterable`. In this way you can do it to arrays or collections.

```
static class Coalesce<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    final Iterable<T> feed;

    public Coalesce(Iterable<T> feed) {
        this.feed = feed;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new ColascingIterator(feed.iterator());
    }

    private static class ColascingIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

        // The Iterator we are feeding off.
        final Iterator<T> it;
        // The last non-null to replace nulls with.
        T last = null;

        public ColascingIterator(Iterator<T> it) {
            this.it = it;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return it.hasNext();
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            T next = it.next();
            // Return last if next is null.
            return next == null ? last : (last = next);
        }

    }

}

public void test() {
    List<String> test = Arrays.asList("Hello", null, "World");
    for (String s : new Coalesce<>(test)) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```